# Chrome devTools Shortcut to clear network tab logs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any shortcut key combination for Google Chrome DevTools Network Tab to clear the logs? Such as `Ctrl`+`L` is used to clear console logs.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (Mac) and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (Windows) twice will do the trick.

Note: Your cursor must focus on DevTools (just click any area of the DevTools) before you use the shortcut. Also please keep in mind that you need to uncheck `Preseve log` option to use the shortcut mentioned above.

[image]

[Chrome DevTools Keyboard Shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts)

Comment: Your screenshot is of a different command (start/stop recording).

Comment: Is it possible to clear the same programatically, the way localStorage can be cleared?

Comment: Either does not work or no longer works. `Ctrl+E` toggles recording network logs, but does not clear existing ones.

Comment: @korulis You are correct that `Ctrl+E` toggles recording network logs. However, when the network logs are toggled on, the network logs are cleared. Thus, toggling the network logs twice, such as by pressing `Ctrl+E` twice, clears the network logs.

Answer (score 9):

You can use @Ben's answer by using 'cmd+E' for mac or 'ctrl+E' in windows -twice, but reminding that you uncheck 'Preserve log' under Network tab.
['Preserve log' under Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekk41.png)

Answer (score 7):

**Chrome 115 and above:** [There are now keyboard shortcuts for this](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-115/#misc), which work while you are focused on the Network tab.

- MacOS: `Command + K`
- Windows/Linux: `Control + L`

**Chrome 114 and below:** If you have Preserve Log checked on the Network tab and want to clear out everything, the easiest way to clear it is to close and reopen dev tools (i.e. press `F12` twice). This won't be helpful in every situation, but is hopefully helpful for some.

Comment: Having *Preserve Log* checked is pretty much the only time I want to clear the network tab, so this is the only useful answer.

Comment: Dev tools hint on using Ctrl + L – Cmd + K shortcut (see [image](https://i.imgur.com/qnJ9T1L.png)), but it does not work for me. Does it work for anybody?

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. It's also worth noting that CTRL+L does clear the console, so wouldn't be suitable for someone wanting to keep the contents of the console but clear the network requests.

Answer (score 6):

There's no such shortcut listed in the [keyboard shortcut reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts). Of course, my doc could be incomplete, so I checked the [Command Menu](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ui#command-menu) also, and there doesn't appear to be a command for this. Also, usually when you hover over a button, if that button has a shortcut, DevTools shows you the shortcut in the tooltip. The **Clear** button doesn't show a shortcut, so I'm pretty confident at this point that a shortcut does not exist.

You can file a feature request at https://crbug.com

Comment: There's a feature request for it here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1302608